# Access denied error while attaching files

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to attach my mdf files to SQL server (using windows XP) but it gives operating system error (error 5), saying Access is denied to the dbMaster.mdf

I gave full control to folder in Windows Vista and 7 and it worked but I did not find how to give control in Windows XP.  Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450032/how-to-attach-mdf-file-to-sqlexpress and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330439/access-is-denied-when-attaching-a-database (although that seems to be a Win7 issue)

Comment: Did not work .........  I have seen over the net, this is the problem of many people.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For XP Professional you may have to uncheck simple file sharing first to see ntfs security tab. Follow these steps (taken from [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/missing-or-no-security-tab-found-in-windows-xp-professional/))

> - Launch Windows Explorer or My Computer.
> - Click on the Tools at the menu bar, then click on Folder Options.
> - Click on View tab.
> - In the Advanced Settings section at the bottom of the list, uncheck    and unselect (clear the tick) on the “Use simple file sharing
>     (Recommended)” check box.
> - Click OK.

For XP Home you could use some 3rd party tool like [FaJo XP File Security Extension](http://www.fajo.de/main/en/software/fajo-xp-fse) to set NTFS permissions.