# In Entity Framework code-first, why can't I use SQL Server Express in the connection string?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-express

I'm building my first ASP.NET MVC application using the code-first approach.

When I changed the default connection string's "Data Source" from:

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0
```

to

```
Data Source=.\Sqlexpress
```

I encountered error about an error contains this:

> A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

When I reverted the changes I made to "Data Source" it worked.

Why did this happened ? Do I have always to use this data source ?

Comment: what is your complete connection string ?

Comment: <add name="MVCAuction.Models.AuctionsDataContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SqlExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AuctionsDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: stop attaching a file, use something like: "Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True". Otherwise read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450032/how-to-attach-mdf-file-to-sqlexpress)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the local db and let code first create it. The message is very clear you have to instruct EF to createIfNotExists.

Comment: The problem is not creating database every time, it's that I've to use '(LocalDb)\v11.0' in Data Source instead of using what I want (like .\SqlExpress for example)

Comment: Try to delete the local db and let code first create it.

Comment: Look at this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318843/localdb-how-do-you-delete-it